# How can I get my animation to stop on the last frame?

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to keep the last frame of my animation visible after it has looped through once. The idea is for a sequence of separate animations to essentially create an image which gradually completes as the user clicks on the last frame of each animation. I was able to get the first animation to just loop once, but then it disappears altogether. Here's what I have so far:

```
onclick = function startAnimation() { 
    var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
    var frameCount = frames.length;
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () { 
        frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
        frames[i++].style.display = "inline";
    },1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the question how to stop an "timer" :

Use clearInterval.

```
var interval = setInterval(function () { 
    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
    frames[i++].style.display = "inline";
    if (i >= frameCount){
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
},1000);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval